# Change input value without id using JS

Tags: javascript, date, input, time

I need to change input value using js by current date and time.
For example, I have such code:

```
<input value="Here should be current date and time">
```

I need to change this value using js by Current date. To get such thing, for example:

```
<input value="02.19.2016, 17:48">
```

Is it possible without using input id?

Comment: Is it the only input on the page? Is there something that makes the input identifiable? Do you know the original value? Is it unique?

Comment: You can obtain all input using JQuery $("input:text")

Comment: You can use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) or [getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Is that what you mean? You have to get the elements some how, you cant just modify it without knowing what "it" is. @CMedina I dont think it is a great idea to recommend an entire library for such a simple task. Especially for somebody new to Javascript.

Comment: value can make this input identifiable. I can set any default value

Comment: If you want to identify it by value then you find all inputs  (`var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input')) and loop over them until you find the value you want (`for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) { if (elements[i].value === 'Here should be current date and time') { elements[i].value = new Date() }}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector()` and look for the input's `value`.

```
document.querySelector('input[value="uniqueValue"]')
```

Then you can just set it's value to the date like below:

```js
var now = new Date();
var dd = now.getDate();
var mm = now.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = now.getFullYear();
var h = now.getHours();
var m = now.getMinutes();
dd = dd < 10 ? '0' + dd : dd
mm = mm < 10 ? '0' + mm : mm;
m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m
h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
now = mm + '.' + dd + '.' + yyyy + ' ' + h + ':' + m;

document.querySelector('input[value="uniqueValue"]').value = now;
```

```html
<input value="uniqueValue"/>
```

Sidenote:

If you already have [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) included on your page (or want to include it), you can also set the date like

```
document.querySelector('input[value="uniqueValue"]').value = moment().format('MM.DD.YYYY HH:mm');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with only one input(which i doubt)

```
var date=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
var d = new Date();
date.value=d;
```

else you are going to need an id or a class name

Comment: Input elements don't have any HTML content, so assigning their innerHTML property is ineffective. They do have a *value* property though, assigning a value to that does have a visible effect. ;-)